# How to locally save gensim glove pretrained vectors?

Tags: python, gensim

I have downloaded the wikipedia glove vectors using the gensim API. I want to save it locally so I don't have to call the API everytime to download it. How can I do this? I have looked but I am not sure if this is the right way to save them.

```
import gensim.downloader as api

vectors = api.load('glove-wiki-gigaword-50')
vectors.save('vectors.bin')
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you've shown in your question likely worked to save the vectors.

You can check the class type of the object that the `api.load()` gave you with code like:

```py
print(type(vectors))
```

I think that will be shown to be an instance of `KeyedVectors`.

If so, then reloading the file you've already saved should be as simple as:

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
reloaded_vectors = KeyedVectors.load('vectors.bin')
```

Note that the native Gensim `.save()`, for any vectors of significant size, will usually be split over multiple files that all start with `vectors.bin` – so if you then want to move the model elsewhere, move all those files together.

You can also save/load vectors in a simpler format with the `.save_word2vec_format()` & `.load_word2vec_format()` methods. EG:

```py
vectors.save_word2vec_format('vectors.txt', binary=False)
```

```py
vectors_reloaded = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('vectors.txt', binary=False)
```